# Custom C-M-; key binding

Tags: key-bindings, terminal-emacs

I have a custom `comment-dwim-line` command that I want to bind to the key combination `C-M-;` (in other words, `control`, `meta` and `;` buttons pressed simultaneously). The built-in `comment-dwim` command is bound to `M-;` by default, and I want to keep this binding.

So far I have tried:

```
(global-set-key "\C-M-;" 'comment-dwim-line)
```

which throws `global-set-key: Key sequence RET - ; starts with non-prefix key RET`.

```
(global-set-key "\C-\M-;" 'comment-dwim-line)
```

which throws `load-with-code-conversion: Invalid modifier in string`.

```
(global-set-key "C-\M-;" 'comment-dwim-line)
```

which throws `global-set-key: Key sequence C - M-; starts with non-prefix key C`.

```
(global-set-key [?\C-M-;] 'next-line)
```

which throws `read--expression: Invalid read syntax: "?"`.

```
(global-set-key [?\C-\M-;] 'next-line)
```

which throws `Symbol's value as variable is void: M-`.

Finally

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-;") 'comment-dwim-line)
```

does not throw an error, but the key binding has no effect: when I actually press `C-M-;` it behaves the same as `M-;`(default `comment-dwim` is called).

I am using Emacs 24.4 on Mac OS X 10.10, running in iTerm2.

Comment: Something happened to your formatting.  In particular, it looks like it chopped off whatever goes wrong when you try `(kbd "C-M-;")`.  That's what I use - could you update with that error message?

Comment: @purple_arrows updated my question, thanks.

Comment: You seem to have still forgotten a right paren after `(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-;") 'comment-dwim-line`.

Comment: @Drew I accidentally deleted final ) when editing the question, it was in the code, but no success.

Comment: Side question: how come some many people use Emacs inside a terminal?  I mean, it's great to see that users do take advantage of the effort we put into providing good support for terminal use, but I'm surprised at how many people seem to use Emacs that way.

Comment: @Stefan I think a lot people still spend time in terminal anyway, even if they have another IDEs running in parallel as a main coding tool. So you need to have a terminal based editor to use for all purposes: organize your notes, edit commit messages, edit sql files, write some script, run shell interpreters for python and erlang with syntax highlight and autocomplete, and some types of coding maybe even easier to do in emacs if you are already familiar with it, etc. And if I am in terminal, I don't want to leave it until I have to or want to completely switch focus.

Comment: Of possible relevance is the thread on [problems with keybindings when using terminal](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/problems-with-keybindings-when-using-terminal).

Answer (score 4):

Your terminal likely translates `C-M-;` to `M-;`. Try testing it out in GUI Emacs.

If it works in the GUI, you'll know it's iTerm2 causing the issue.

Comment: He's indeed likely using the terminal, not all key combos will work inside a terminal, so he would need a different keybinding, if the same behaviour is expected for GUI and console usage.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a backslash, `\`, before `M`.

```el
(global-set-key [?\C-\M-;] 'next-line)
```

This one is OK (except you forgot the final `)`).

```el
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-;") 'comment-dwim-line)
```

This one does not work for `;` (but it would work for `"\C-\M-y"`, for instance).

```el
(global-set-key "\C-\M-;" 'comment-dwim-line)
```

---

Finally, you say:

> `(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-;") 'comment-dwim-line)`
>   does not throw an error, but the key binding has no effect: when I actually press `C-M-;` it behaves the same as `M-;` (default `comment-dwim` is called).

I don't see that.  Do you see this problem if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If so, provide a step-by-step recipe, starting with `emacs -Q` to reproduce it.  If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

It works fine for me, on MS Windows, with all versions of Emacs (20 and later):

1. `emacs -Q --debug-init -nw`
2. Evaluate this:

   ```
   (defun comment-dwim-line () (interactive) (message "FOOOOOOOOO"))
   (global-set-key (kbd "C-M-;") 'comment-dwim-line)
   ```
3. `C-h k C-M-;`

   > `C-M-;` runs the command `comment-dwim-line` (found in `global-map`), which
   >   is an interactive Lisp function.
   >
   > It is bound to `C-M-;`.
   >
   > `(comment-dwim-line)`
   >
   > Not documented.
4. `C-M-;` shows the message `FOOOOOOOOO` in the echo area.

Comment: I accidentally deleted final `)` when editing the question, it was in the code, but no success.

Answer (score 1):

Terminal emulators do not forward all possible key combinations to the shell, so Emacs likely does not see `C-M-;` when used in the terminal.  You can visualize the command processed by your terminal emulator (iTerm2 in your case) by pressing `C+v` (`CTRL`+`v`) in the terminal, followed by a key combination.  For `C-v C-M-;` I get with the XFCE terminal under Linux

```
$ ^[;
```

which is the same as `M-;`, so the `CTRL` key is basically ignored.

A possible workaround is to define an alternate key combination in Emacs, let us say `C-c M-;`, and to instruct iTerm2 to forward this combination when you press `C-M-;`.  This way you can use the keys that you want in iTerm2, but Emacs will behave as if you pressed `C-M-;`.  I have done this previously, but I do not have a Mac at hand right now to search for the iTerm2 options.

**Edit:**
Just found this related question: [Shift+Up isn't recognized by Emacs in a terminal](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/977)

Comment: Of possible relevance is the thread on [problems with keybindings when using terminal](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/problems-with-keybindings-when-using-terminal).