# Why I can't bind Shift-<backspace>?

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, prefix-keys

My system is debian wheezy, I tried to do the following

```
(global-set-key (kbd "S-<backspace>") 'evil-shift-left-line)
(global-set-key (kbd "<S-backspace>") 'evil-shift-left-line)
(define-key global-map [S-backspace] 'evil-shift-left-line)
```

What I want is in evil insert mode, I can delete one tab width forward instead of press backspace 4 times. 
The keybinding works on my laptop, but doen't work on my desktop. I check the binding for evil-shift-left-line, it has changed but doesn't work, and help on "shift-backspace" only shows "backspace". However, shift do has effect on "backspace", "shift-backspace" delete the previous word instead of character.

When I insert "shift-backspace" after "C-q", it has the same notation "^?" as "backspace" on my desktop, while on my laptop the former is "^@".

Any ideas on why it doesn't work on my desktop?
Thank you for your help!

This question may be related to this one:
[Shift+Up isn't recognized by Emacs in a terminal](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/977/shiftup-isnt-recognized-by-emacs-in-a-terminal)

Comment: Are you using Emacs on a terminal?

Comment: No, I am using the stand alone emacs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interestingly, you can try binding the `deletechar` [pseudo key](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsKeyNotation).

When I check the binding of <kbd>backspace</kbd> on my machine with `C-h k [backspace]`, I get:

> `DEL` (translated from `<backspace>`) runs the command... (blah blah blah)

When I check the binding of <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>backspace</kbd> on my machine with `C-h k S-[backspace]`, I get:

> `<deletechar>` (translated from `<delete>`) runs the command... (blah blah blah)

The following therefore works on my machine:

```
(global-set-key [deletechar] #'evil-shift-left-line)
```

Comment: On my computer, when I check the binding of shift key + <backspace> is <backspace>.

Answer (score 2):

I have this in my setup:

```
(define-key global-map [(shift backspace)] 'backward-delete-whitespace)
(define-key global-map [(shift delete)] 'forward-delete-whitespace)
```

to make shift+backspace / shift+delete kill all whitespace.

---

And just in case someone would need these functions, here they are:

```
(defun backward-delete-whitespace ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((p (point)))
    (re-search-backward "[^ \t\n]+" nil t)
    (forward-char)
    (delete-region p (point))))

(defun forward-delete-whitespace ()
  (interactive)
  (re-search-forward "[ \t\n]+" nil t)
  (replace-match "" nil nil))
```

Answer (score 1):

I am now happy with this setting.

```
(defun my/backspace()
  (interactive)
  (if (string-match "[^[:space:]]+"
                    (buffer-substring-no-properties
     (line-beginning-position) (point))) ;; return nil no match
      (backward-kill-word 1)(evil-shift-left-line)))
```