# 'C-M--' on Emacs Terminal on OSX fails with "C-M-_ is undefined"

Tags: key-bindings, osx, terminal-emacs, term

I'm trying to execute `C-M--` from Emacs on Terminal (iTerm2) running on OSX, but I keep getting an error saying `C-M-_ is undefined`. Any ideas how to workaround this?

Comment: Using `M--` works, but makes it a bit awkward for scrolling up on other window. Note that this is Emacs Terminal and hence `C-M-S-v` does not work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shift+Up isn't recognized by Emacs in a terminal](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/977/shiftup-isnt-recognized-by-emacs-in-a-terminal)

Comment: @PythonNut Not a duplicate. http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/977/shiftup-isnt-recognized-by-emacs-in-a-terminal is definitely useful background, but an answer to this question would explain how to set up iTerm2. Hmm, I've done that before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems with keybindings when using terminal](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/problems-with-keybindings-when-using-terminal)

Comment: @Gilles @PythonNut can you be more specific how this is a duplicate? And @Gilles, any specific ideas on how to solve this? Looking at the output of `C-h l`, I see `ESC C-_` being printed out when I execute `C-M--`

Comment: @GalderZamarreño So configure the iTerm2 binding for Ctrl+Meta+-.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got this working by going into iTerm2 preferences and adding a new global shortcut key binding where I entered as Keyboard Shortcut `^⌥-`, chose Action `Send Escape Sequence` and just typed `-` in the Esc+ field. That seems to do the trick.

Thanks @Gilles and @PythonNut for their help :)

Comment: If you're satisfied with this answer, could you please accept it so we can mark it as answered?