# C-S-n and C-= not working in emacs if running within terminal

Tags: key-bindings, terminal-emacs, gui-emacs

I am running emacs inside tmux within iterm2 on OSX. For some reason these key bindings do not work properly

```
C-S-n
C-=
C-+
C-;
```

And some others too that are similar.
All of these work when running within X.
Any ideas why?

I'd hate to revert `C-=` to `C-c =` in terminal mode.

Comment: [Problems with keybindings when using terminal](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/problems-with-keybindings-when-using-terminal/1056#1056)

Comment: [Shift+Up isn't recognized by Emacs in a terminal](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/977/115)