# How to bind meta-shift-arrow to mark one word at a time

Tags: key-bindings, mark

I am having trouble of marking one word at a time (ctrl-shift-arrow or meta-shift f/b) when connecting from one of my terminals. I would like to bind it also to meta-shift-arrow.

I couldn't find what are the commands to do it.

Any idea?

EDIT: I am looking for something like (pseudocode) `(global-set-key (kbd "M-S-right") 'mark-word-right)`

If it's relevant, I am using CUA mode.

Comment: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/977 possible duplication?

Comment: @YasushiShoji, I added an EDIT clarifying why its not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You were just using the wrong key description text as the argument to `kbd`.  (You can see how to write a key sequence by using `C-h k` and using the key sequence.)

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-S-<right>") 'mark-word-right)
```

(Of course, `mark-word-right` needs to be a defined command.)