# How can I temporarily disable Spacemacs key bindings to work with org mode?

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, spacemacs, evil

I am trying to learn an orgmode tutorial in Spacemacs (terminal mode) and it seems tha the Spacemacs key bindings are getting in the way.

How can I revert the Spacemacs bindings temporarily for that session, or that buffer if possible?

The other problem I have is when I ssh into another user account to edit the file in standards emacs (also terminal mode) the Alt - Arrow keys don't work. They are replaced by character codes. such as `3A` and `3C`

UPDATE: It turns out my problem came from Alt,Shift and Ctrl cursor combinations not working in my terminal configuration. The fix for that is in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375825/how-can-emacs-be-configured-to-accept-shift-and-alt-cursor-combinations-properly and it is also related to [Shift+Up isn't recognized by Emacs in a terminal](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/977/shiftup-isnt-recognized-by-emacs-in-a-terminal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can switch from Evil mode back to Emacs-state using `M-x evil-emacs-state`, which by default is bound to `C-z`.